# An idiomatic meaning of "call" in "-How about a club? -...call."

Tags: idiomatic-language

There will be not much context since I don't remember the exact novel it came from.

Two characters are talking after a hard day. The setting is close to the current time.

> -How about a club?
>   -...call.

After that, the conversation has ended.

In the informal setting, is it widespread to use **call** in such a minimized form to mean **it's your call**, i.e. **you decide**?

Comment: It's hard to know what they were talking about.

Comment: I've never heard one-word ***call*** used as a response meaning ***It's your call***. I think more likely (particularly given preceding ***club***, which can refer to a playing card suit) it's a loose allusion / "pun" to the same response in the context of, say, ***betting in a poker game***. Modifying the semantics to suit the *exact* context, I'm tempted to interpret it as meaning *[That's a] **good call**!* with an allusion to ***I'm up for continuing** [to bet, to interact socially, whatever]*.

Comment: Barring any other context, the question is impossible to answer. If that's ***all*** I heard, I would assume the second sentence meant *[give them a] call [and find out].* Or simply *call [them].* I can think of no normal interpretation of *only* those two sentences that would mean *it's your call*. As opposed to the previous comment, which is also a valid interpretation since we have no context, I would interpret *club* to mean *bar* or *lounge*, and *How about a club?* to mean *How about [we all go to] a club?* And, overall, there are absent friends whose opinion is to be asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the comments, there are different possible interpretations given the lack of context.

Starting from *call* in its literal meaning and ending at the poker term meaning.